# How can I download only metadata from a Google Sites API content feed?

Tags: python, gdata

I want to download a list of URLs for pages in my Google Sites site.  I'm using the Python API to do this.  It seems to be slower than I would expect, and so I think it's actually downloading the whole content for each entry rather than just the metadata.  Is there any way to download just the metadata?  My code is below:

```
import gdata.sites.client

client = gdata.sites.client.SitesClient(site='mysite', domain='mydomain.com')
client.ClientLogin('foo@bar.com', 'password', 'test')
feed = client.GetContentFeed()
for entry in feed.entry:
    print entry.GetAlternateLink().href
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest approximation is

```
https://sites.google.com/site/(your site name)/system/feeds/sitemap
```

Unfortunately, this API doesn't allow the use of `fields` as some newer Google APIs do.